# Visualização 3D no Angular Google Maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

### Preâmbulo

Eu utilizo [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/) para indicar a localização de vários prédios no *campus* de uma universidade. Minha inicialização é a seguinte:

```
 $scope.map = {
                    control: {},
                    center:
                    {
                        latitude: $scope.Item.Latitude,
                        longitude: $scope.Item.Longitude
                    },
                    zoom: 16,
                    options: {
                        streetViewControl: true,
                        maxZoom: 20,
                        minZoom: 8,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                    },
                    showTraffic: true,
                    showBicycling: true,
                    events: {
                        blacklist: ['drag', 'dragend', 'dragstart', 'center_changed']
                    }
              };
```

Esse procedimento está funcionando, e permite a vizualização da seguinte maneira:

[image]

Entretanto, recentemente percebi que o Google Maps possui informação 3D da área coberta, e eu gostaria que o mapa fosse renderizado da seguinte maneira:

[image]

### Pergunta

É possível, via via Angular Google Maps, configurar a inicialização do meu mapa de maneira a exibi-lo da maneira indicada?

### Pergunta-bônus

...Seria possível girar a "câmera" programaticamente centrando na posição indicada de maneira a fazer o prédio girar?

---

Link de referência para a área indicada:
https://www.google.com/maps/@40.9570608,-76.8816097,179a,20y,180h,41.69t/data=!3m1!1e3

<sub>**Disclaimer**: Este é um cross-post do SO original, 
*[3D map visualization in Angular Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506714/3d-map-visualization-in-angular-%20google-maps)*</sub>

Comment: Traz a resposta de lá pra cá.

Comment: Conseguiu Resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como poderia fazer o google exibir de maneira 3D, porem girar consegui montar um exemplo. Talvez o que pode fazer é mudar a inclinação na propriedade  **tilt**, para parecer 3D, neste exemplo o tilt é 45.

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat:37.4274745 , lng: -122.1719077},
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    heading: 90,
    tilt: 45
  });
}

function rotate90() {
  var heading = map.getHeading() || 0;
  map.setHeading(heading + 90);
}

function autoRotate() {
  // Determine if we're showing aerial imagery.
  if (map.getTilt() !== 0) {
    window.setInterval(rotate90, 3000);
  }
}
```

```css
 html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Girando Imagem</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel"><input type="button" value="Girar" onclick="autoRotate();"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA1DxXp2RnMhOirzR8NVtYNJf6p_yW_qo0&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```